# Expecting his call vs waiting for his call ,what is the difference?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference difference between " I am expecting your call " and " I am waiting for your call " and " I am looking forward to receiving your call"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Waiting adds the nuance that you are actively thinking about the call before it is received, and that you wont be able to do something untill it is received. Similar to how you cannot go anywhere as you wait for a bus to arrive.

Expect does not imply this, and it feels more demanding.

Looking forward to receiving is standard cordiall English that is frequently used in formal situations. You could use this phrase for a business call, for example.

Answer (score 4):

- *expecting your call* means that I am confident that you will call.
- *waiting for your call* means that that some other action is suspended until I hear from you.
- *looking forward to your call* means that your calling will be a pleasure for me.

Those are literal meanings or first-order implications; in some contexts they may be polite ways of expressing a demand or threat.